# Kubernetes lost control plane on 3 node HA cluster

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 3 HA nodes on 3 different servers. One of the server had the control plane and got deleted (meaning, I lost the server).

Right now, other two servers are running normally and all deployments and services are running, however I don't have any access to the cluster.

How can I recover this scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring a lost control plane node is very troublesome if you haven’t taken snapshots of the instance and the backup of ETCD data, then follow these steps as mentioned in this **[blog](https://www.lisenet.com/2023/replacing-a-failed-control-plane-node-in-a-ha-kubernetes-cluster/)**.

- Check whether the control plane is in `Not Ready` state and check
  whether you have the etcd client installed in the nodes, else
  install it.
- Now remove the etcd member which is associated with the deleted
  control plane from the other two nodes after checking the etcd
  member status.
- Now create a new node using the existing snapshot else create a new
  instance and install kubernetes control plane components.
- Join the nodes to the new control plane node using the new token
  generated.

Follow the above blog for more information on instructions related to installing etcd client and other commands.